# Facing issues with Spring Boot's @Cacheable and @CachePut - cache is always empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, service

I'm trying to build a simple Java SB application that reads a text file with lines of data such as:

`{"id":"15887","customer_id":"528","load_amount":"$3318.47","time":"2000-01-01T00:00:00Z"}`

I am struggling to understand why my cache continues to be empty even though I explicitly call methods within my UpdateCacheService (annotated with either @Cacheable or @Cacheput). I have abstracted methods that interacting with the Cache into the UpdateCacheService, although I'm unsure as to whether my various annotations and general setup are correct.

I tried creating a service named UpdateCacheService that contains various methods annotated with @Cacheable and @Cacheput. To my understanding, @Cacheable will check the cache for any corresponding values based on the provided key, and if something's found then the function thereafter won't be invoked. @Cacheput is quite the contrary in which the function is invoked, and the return value of the function will be stored as a value to the provided key as a key:value pair in the cache. I've created a service to house all of my various cache operations:

```
package com.example.fundloader.service;

import com.example.fundloader.model.DailyLoadInfo;
import com.example.fundloader.model.Load;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachePut;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import static com.example.fundloader.constants.ApplicationConstants.DAILY_LOADS_CACHE;
import static com.example.fundloader.constants.ApplicationConstants.WEEKLY_LOADS_CACHE;

@Service
public class UpdateCacheService {
    @Cacheable(value = DAILY_LOADS_CACHE, key = "#load.customerId")
    public DailyLoadInfo loadCachedCustomerDailyData(Load load) {
        return null;
    }

    @Cacheable(value = WEEKLY_LOADS_CACHE, key = "#load.customer_id")
    public BigDecimal loadCachedCustomerWeeklyTotal(Load load) {
        return new BigDecimal(0);
    }

    @CachePut(value = DAILY_LOADS_CACHE, key = "#load.customerId")
    public DailyLoadInfo insertRecordIntoCache(DailyLoadInfo dailyCustomerLoadInfo) {

        return dailyCustomerLoadInfo;
    }

    @CachePut(value = WEEKLY_LOADS_CACHE, key = "#load.customerId")
    public BigDecimal updateWeeklyCache(BigDecimal total) {
        return total;
    }

    @CacheEvict(value = "#cacheName", allEntries = true)
    public void clearCache(String cacheName) {
    }
}
```

Along with another Service thats sole purpose is to accept lines of input from the text file that I'm reading off from and invoke both the UpdateCacheService and another ValidateLoadService, which essentially just checks the current input against certain constraints that I've imposed on myself (i.e if a given *customer_id* has made more than 3 deposits in a single day, deny them, or if they've deposited >$5,000/day).

CacheManagementService.java

```
import static com.example.fundloader.constants.ApplicationConstants.DAILY_LOADS_CACHE;
import static com.example.fundloader.constants.ApplicationConstants.WEEKLY_LOADS_CACHE;

@Service
public class CacheManagementService {
    private final CacheManager cacheManager;
    private final UpdateCacheService updateCacheService;
    private final ValidateLoadService validateLoadService;
    private Instant lastSeenDate;

    @Autowired
    public CacheManagementService(CacheManager cacheManager, UpdateCacheService updateCacheService, ValidateLoadService validateLoadService) {
        this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
        this.updateCacheService = updateCacheService;
        this.validateLoadService = validateLoadService;
    }


    public Boolean processLoad(Load load) {
        if (this.lastSeenDate != null) {
            syncCacheCalendar(this.lastSeenDate, load.getTransactionDate());
        }

        //Read value in from cache if available
        DailyLoadInfo dailyCustomerLoadInfo = this.updateCacheService.loadCachedCustomerDailyData(load);
        BigDecimal weeklyLoadAmount = this.updateCacheService.loadCachedCustomerWeeklyTotal(load);

        Boolean isValidInput = this.validateLoadService.isValidLoad(load, dailyCustomerLoadInfo, weeklyLoadAmount);
        if (isValidInput == null) {
            return null; // Duplicate load_id for unique user
        } else if (!isValidInput) {
            return false;
        }

        //TODO: Write to DB Service

        if (dailyCustomerLoadInfo == null) {
            dailyCustomerLoadInfo = assignCustomerLoad(load);
        } else {
            adjustDailyCustomerLoad(load, dailyCustomerLoadInfo);
        }

        boolean isDatabaseSuccess = true;

        if (isDatabaseSuccess) {
            this.lastSeenDate = this.updateCacheService.insertRecordIntoCache(dailyCustomerLoadInfo).getTransactionDate();
            this.updateCacheService.updateWeeklyCache(load.getLoadAmount().add(weeklyLoadAmount));
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Within my processLoad() function in CacheManagementService.java, I invoke

`DailyLoadInfo dailyCustomerLoadInfo = this.updateCacheService.loadCachdCustomerDailyData(load);`

and my expectation was that on the first hit, it would be a cache miss since the cache is empty. Given that my text file contains a fair amount of duplicates with respect to *customer_id*'s, I know there are cases where I provide a key:value pair where the key has been seen before. With that being said, I don't know why my cache continues to be empty even after processing >1000 lines of my text file. I've tried accessing the cache directly by doing `cacheManager.get(<cacheName>).get(<key>)`, all to no avail (all return null). I can only assume that I've either set my dependency injections up incorrectly, or that I've missed and/or missed certain annotations such as @EnableCaching in vital places.

Main.java

```
package com.example.fundloader;

import com.example.fundloader.utils.FileIO;
import com.example.fundloader.model.Load;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
public class FundLoaderApplication {

    private final FileIO<Load> loadsFileProcessor;

    @Autowired
    public FundLoaderApplication(FileIO<Load> loadsFileProcessor) {
        this.loadsFileProcessor = loadsFileProcessor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FundLoaderApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void processFiles() {
        loadsFileProcessor.processFile("src/main/resources/");
    }
}
```

CacheConfig.java

```
package com.example.fundloader.config;

import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import static com.example.fundloader.constants.ApplicationConstants.DAILY_LOADS_CACHE;
import static com.example.fundloader.constants.ApplicationConstants.WEEKLY_LOADS_CACHE;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class LoadCacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager(DAILY_LOADS_CACHE, WEEKLY_LOADS_CACHE);
    }
}
```

I'd greatly appreciate any help, I've been stuck for a few days now and I'm unsure on how to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure because I haven't seen the entire code, but I think it's because the first caching is always null, but this value isn't updated properly.

First, since the return value from loadCachedCustomerDailyData() is null, it will always return the cached null value.
Therefore, dailyCustomerLoadInfo in the processLoad method will perform logic with a null value.

I don't know what processLoad's isValidLoad() and assignCustomerLoad() do, but I predict that the logic is not working as expected because the first caching is always null.

Try logging for each condition and debug methods that are executed with null values. Hope this helps!

I have commented the code below.

```java
@Service
public class UpdateCacheService {

    @Cacheable(value = DAILY_LOADS_CACHE, key = "#load.customerId")
    public DailyLoadInfo loadCachedCustomerDailyData(Load load) {
        // null value caching!
        return null;
    }

    @Cacheable(value = WEEKLY_LOADS_CACHE, key = "#load.customer_id")
    public BigDecimal loadCachedCustomerWeeklyTotal(Load load) {
        return new BigDecimal(0);
    }

    @CachePut(value = DAILY_LOADS_CACHE, key = "#load.customerId")
    public DailyLoadInfo insertRecordIntoCache(DailyLoadInfo dailyCustomerLoadInfo) {

        return dailyCustomerLoadInfo;
    }

    @CachePut(value = WEEKLY_LOADS_CACHE, key = "#load.customerId")
    public BigDecimal updateWeeklyCache(BigDecimal total) {
        return total;
    }

    @CacheEvict(value = "#cacheName", allEntries = true)
    public void clearCache(String cacheName) {
    }
}
```

```java
public Boolean processLoad(Load load) {
        if (this.lastSeenDate != null) {
            syncCacheCalendar(this.lastSeenDate, load.getTransactionDate());
        }

        //Read value in from cache if available
        //First, cached null values!
        DailyLoadInfo dailyCustomerLoadInfo = this.updateCacheService.loadCachedCustomerDailyData(load);
        BigDecimal weeklyLoadAmount = this.updateCacheService.loadCachedCustomerWeeklyTotal(load);
        //It will always go into the dailyCustomerLoadInfo == null conditional branch below.
        Boolean isValidInput = this.validateLoadService.isValidLoad(load, dailyCustomerLoadInfo, weeklyLoadAmount);
        if (isValidInput == null) {
            return null; // Duplicate load_id for unique user
        } else if (!isValidInput) {
            return false;
        }

        //TODO: Write to DB Service
        //It will always go into the null conditional branch below.
        if (dailyCustomerLoadInfo == null) {
            // I don't know assignCustomerLoad method...
            dailyCustomerLoadInfo = assignCustomerLoad(load);
        } else {
            adjustDailyCustomerLoad(load, dailyCustomerLoadInfo);
        }

        boolean isDatabaseSuccess = true;
                
        // The null update is interesting for caching updates under the conditions below..
        if (isDatabaseSuccess) {
            this.lastSeenDate = this.updateCacheService.insertRecordIntoCache(dailyCustomerLoadInfo).getTransactionDate();
            this.updateCacheService.updateWeeklyCache(load.getLoadAmount().add(weeklyLoadAmount));
        }
        return true;
    }
```